# What are the benefits and purpose of presenting a paper in an academic conference?

Tags: publications, journals, conference

If i have completed all the research work and compiled a research article then why should I present that paper in a conference and not submit it to a good journal for publication ?

Comment: What is your field of research? This seems like a question you should discuss with your adviser.

Comment: @Roland Manufacturing Engineering

Comment: @JeffE Editing now done

Comment: You're still presenting a false dichotomy.  Why not do both?

Comment: @JeffE Is it permitted to submit the same paper to a conference and a journal ?

Comment: It certainly is in my field.  Not at the same time, but conference first and then journal is completely standard, usually with some additional material in the journal version.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the discipline.

In many disciplines you **can do both**. There are conferences where you can present work that has been published in a journal (or at another conference) or that shall be published in the future.

In other disciplines, conference publications are as "valuable" (or even more prestigious) than journal publications.

To know what is the case for your discipline, talk to your advisor.